# Is there a software like XPlite for Windows 7 and beyond?

Tags: windows, windows-7

[XPlite](http://www.litepc.com/xplite.html) had power to remove unwanted features that cannot be removed from the standard component manager,  the power to remove upgrades , *the power to strip potential security and privacy threats out by the roots.*

But it is discontinued and no longer available.

Is there a software like XPlite for Windows 7 and beyond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like WinReducer, RT7 lite, Win Toolkit, vLite or [similar alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/xplite/).

Comment: Links to external lists of alternatives is not encouraged as answers should be recommending *specific* software.